# php preg_match() code for comma separated names

Tags: php, regex

I need to validate input patterns using `preg_match()` so that the patterns is like " anyname1,anyname2,anyname3, ".

Note that there is a comma at the end too. Any letter or number is valid between the commas, numbers do not have to appear at the end.  e.g  "nam1e,Na2me,NNm22," is valid.

I tried `^([A-Za-z0-9] *, *)*[A-Za-z0-9]$` but did no work. I have gone through other posts too but did not get a perfect answer.

Can someone give me an answer for this?

Comment: So you want to validate that the string contains a series of comma separated alpha-numeric substrings, with an optional trailing comma, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to validate that the string contains a series of comma separated alpha-numeric substrings, with an optional trailing comma.

In that situation, this should achieve what you want.

```
$str = "anyname1,anyname2,anyname3,";

$re = '~^([a-z0-9]+,)+$~i';

if (preg_match($re, $str)) {
    // String matches the pattern!
}
else {
    // Nope!
}
```

If the value stored in `$str` contains a trailing space like in your example, and you don't want to use trim() on the value, the following regex will allow for whitespace at the end of `$str`:

```
~^([a-z0-9]+,)+\s*$~i
```

Comment: That regular expression doesn't allow for the /optional/ comma at the end. This one does `^([a-z0-9]+,?)+$`

Comment: From the original question: "Note that there is a comma at the end too."

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the actual values without the comma, then you can simply use this:

`\w+(?=[,])`

http://regex101.com/r/xT6wE4/1

Comment: This works fine so far. But how to catch the last expression even if the last character is not a comma? For example `anyname1,anyname2,anyname3` ?

Answer (score 1):

Why use such a complex solution for a simple problem? You can do the same in two steps:

1: trim spaces, line feeds, line returns and comma's:

```
$line = trim($line," \r\n,");
```

2: explode on comma's to see all the names:

```
$array = explode(',',$line);
```

You're not telling us what you're going to use it for, so I cannot know which format you really need. But my point is that you don't need complex string functions to do simple tasks.

Comment: I agree. But if you really want to use preg_match, try playing with an online tester like http://preg_match.onlinephpfunctions.com

Comment: That doesn't validate the string though, it simply gives you an array of strings, which still need to be validated.

Comment: @Stephan: Loop said: "any character or number is valid between the commas".

Comment: The regex the OP included indicates that he means any letter or number, not any character.

Comment: Clearly one of the mistakes in the regex.

Comment: I disagree, its one of the parts the OP had basically working, if a little verbose.

Answer (score 0):

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+,)+$
```

You can simply do this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/8

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
function implodeForRegex($itemRex, $glue) {
    return "(" . $itemRex . $glue ")*" . $itemRex;
}
...
preg_match('/' . implodeForRegex('([\d]+)', ',') . '/', $string)
```